# log4j2 LoggerContext not showing up in JMX Gui or JConsole

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jmx, log4j2

My Google foo is letting me down today!  I am trying to configure log4j2 so that I can access the loggers via JMX and change their log levels.

However, when I hook everything up, none of the loggers show up in the JMX tree (or log4j-jmx-gui) as shown in the [log4j2 JMX docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/jmx.html#ClientGUI).  Only the log4j2 ContextSelector and StatusLogger in the JConsole attribute tree and the StatusLogger tab in the log4j-jmx-gui (stand-alone or as a plugin) show up.  No LoggerContext elements.

I've googled and not come up with anything!  That probably means I'm missing something somewhere.  Any help would be greatly appreciated by me and wall which I'm banging my head against :)

I'm using Log4j2 beta9 with Java 1.6.0_45-b06 on win7.  I have tried it on Java 7 and it results in the same behaviour.

The log4j2 dependencies being used:

```
log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar
log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar
```

My log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration  status="debug">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="log-test" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DATE} %-5p LJX2 %c{1}: %m%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="top.Log4J2TestApp" level="debug"  additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="log-test" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="log-test" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My test program:

```
package top;   
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Log4J2TestApp { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("******** Started ZZZ ****************");
        Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Log4J2TestApp.class);
        int cnt = 0;
        while (true) {
            log.warn("=========== Test message: {} ================", cnt++);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the test program looks like this:

```
******** Started ZZZ ****************
2013-11-06 15:07:29,720 DEBUG Generated plugins in 0.000020959 seconds
2013-11-06 15:07:29,733 DEBUG Calling createLayout on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout for element PatternLayout with params(pattern="%d{DATE} %-5p LJX2 %c{1}: %m%n", Configuration(log4j2.xml), null, charset="null",alwaysWriteExceptions="null")
2013-11-06 15:07:29,735 DEBUG Generated plugins in 0.000013687 seconds
2013-11-06 15:07:29,737 DEBUG Calling createAppender on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender for element Console with params(PatternLayout(%d{DATE} %-5p LJX2 %c{1}: %m%n), null, target="SYSTEM_OUT", name="log-test",follow="null", ignoreExceptions="null")
2013-11-06 15:07:29,739 DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream2013-11-06 15:07:29,740 DEBUG Calling createAppenders on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.AppendersPlugin for element Appenders with params(Appenders={log-test})
2013-11-06 15:07:29,742 DEBUG Generated plugins in 0.000012832 seconds
2013-11-06 15:07:29,743 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element AppenderRef with params(ref="log-test", level="null", null)
2013-11-06 15:07:29,746 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig for element Logger with params(additivity="false", level="debug", name="top.Log4J2TestApp", includeLocation="null", AppenderRef={log-test}, Properties={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), null)
2013-11-06 15:07:29,749 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element AppenderRef with params(ref="log-test", level="null", null)
2013-11-06 15:07:29,751 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger for element Root with params(additivity="null", level="trace", includeLocation="null", AppenderRef={log-test}, Properties={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), null)
2013-11-06 15:07:29,754 DEBUG Calling createLoggers on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.LoggersPluginfor element Loggers with params(Loggers={top.Log4J2TestApp, root})
2013-11-06 15:07:29,755 DEBUG Reconfiguration completed
06 Nov 2013 15:07:29,763 WARN  LJX2 Log4J2TestApp: =========== Test message: 0 ================
....
06 Nov 2013 15:07:36,766 WARN  LJX2 Log4J2TestApp: =========== Test message: 7 ================

2013-11-06 15:07:51,450 DEBUG ServletContext not present - WebLookup not added
2013-11-06 15:07:51,451 DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT
```

The StatusLogger tab in the log4j-jmx-gui does have one exception but it would seem to have nothing to do with the loggers.

```
2013-11-06 15:41:01,403 WARN Multiple logging implementations found: 
Factory: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory, Weighting: 10
Using factory: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory
2013-11-06 15:41:01,505 WARN JmDNS or serviceInfo class not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jmdns.JmDNS
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.MulticastDNSAdvertiser.initializeJMDNS(MulticastDNSAdvertiser.java:228)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.MulticastDNSAdvertiser.<clinit>(MulticastDNSAdvertiser.java:41)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginManager.decode(PluginManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginManager.collectPlugins(PluginManager.java:152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginManager.collectPlugins(PluginManager.java:130)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.<init>(PatternParser.java:116)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.<init>(PatternParser.java:102)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.createPatternParser(PatternLayout.java:183)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.<init>(PatternLayout.java:115)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.createLayout(PatternLayout.java:219)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.<init>(DefaultConfiguration.java:51)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<init>(LoggerContext.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:81)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:83)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:34)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:387)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:332)
    at top.Log4J2TestApp.main(Log4J2TestApp.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)

2013-11-06 15:41:01,612 DEBUG Generated plugins in 0.000017537 seconds
2013-11-06 15:41:01,625 DEBUG Calling createLayout on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout for element PatternLayout with params(pattern="%d{DATE} %-5p LJX2 %c{1}: %m%n", Configuration(log4j2.xml), null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null")
2013-11-06 15:41:01,627 DEBUG Generated plugins in 0.000011977 seconds
2013-11-06 15:41:01,629 DEBUG Calling createAppender on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender for element Console with params(PatternLayout(%d{DATE} %-5p LJX2 %c{1}: %m%n), null, target="SYSTEM_OUT", name="log-test", follow="null", ignoreExceptions="null")
2013-11-06 15:41:01,631 DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2013-11-06 15:41:01,632 DEBUG Calling createAppenders on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.AppendersPlugin for element Appenders with params(Appenders={log-test})
2013-11-06 15:41:01,633 DEBUG Generated plugins in 0.000011977 seconds
2013-11-06 15:41:01,635 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element AppenderRef with params(ref="log-test", level="null", null)
2013-11-06 15:41:01,637 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig for element Logger with params(additivity="false", level="debug", name="top.Log4J2TestApp", includeLocation="null", AppenderRef={log-test}, Properties={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), null)
2013-11-06 15:41:01,640 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element AppenderRef with params(ref="log-test", level="null", null)
2013-11-06 15:41:01,642 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger for element Root with params(additivity="null", level="trace", includeLocation="null", AppenderRef={log-test}, Properties={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), null)
2013-11-06 15:41:01,644 DEBUG Calling createLoggers on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.LoggersPlugin for element Loggers with params(Loggers={top.Log4J2TestApp, root})
2013-11-06 15:41:01,646 DEBUG Reconfiguration completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config looks good, the only thing a bit suspicious is the error. The error does seem to occur in the LoggerContext constructor, so it may be related after all.

You may have found a bug. Would you mind reporting this issue in the log4j2 issue tracker so the log4j team can look at it?

Comment: hi Remko, thanks for the quick reply.  Issue raised as [LOG4J2-443](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-443).

Answer (score 1):

Log4j2 uses `ClassLoaderContextSelector` as `ContextSelector` by default. In some cases (it is not clear for me, may be for simple applications like yours) it returns nothing as `getLoggerContexts()` method call result. No logger contexts - nothing no show, so `LoggerContext` category doesn't present in the tree. It can be fixed by selecting another `ContextSelector` implementation. I used `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.BasicContextSelector` for this purpose. It can be set using system property named "Log4jContextSelector". See [docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#ContextSelector) for more info.

It solves my problem, I hope it helps to solve yours too.